# Remote validation displaying red box but no error message? ASP - MVC 5

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, json, asp.net-mvc-5

So, I am trying to use custom validation for Username and Email, but it is working but only gives a red box. It's not actually displaying.. This is my code

```
[Required]
    [Display(Name = "User name")]
    [System.Web.Mvc.Remote("UserExists", "Account", ErrorMessage = "UserName already exists, please pick another one.")]
    [Editable(true)]
```

The controller ...
 public JsonResult UserExists(string UserName)
            {

```
        var user = UserManager.FindByName(UserName);

        return Json(!db.AspNetUsers.Any(x => x.UserName == UserName),
                                   JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

So yeah, it's displaying the red box which is proving that the username exists but it's not actually displaying the  error message. If I was to then submit it would display the error message but otherwise not.
This is the model..

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-2.0.3.js"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<fieldset>
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <h4>Create a new account.</h4>
    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary()
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.UserName, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserName, new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.UserName)
        </div>
```

Comment: What does the view look like? Are you actually outputting the error message e.g. `@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.UserName)`

Comment: Hey, I've updated it..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what you want to implement the functionality:

```
public JsonResult UserExists(string UserName) {

    var user = UserManager.FindByName(UserName);
    if (!db.AspNetUsers.Any(x => x.UserName == UserName))
    return Json(true, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

   return Json(string.Format("{0} is not available", UserName) , JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

}
```

Update your Remote tag to this:

```
[Remote("UserExists", "Account")]
```

Which simply removes the error message, basically anything other than a true return is the error message sent back to the client.

More info is available here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg508808(v=vs.98).aspx

Comment: Hi cheers for the info, returning the error message is definitely the best idea. As to my original problem it's still doing it. It's still only giving a red box and Then giving the error message once the page has been refreshed,.

Comment: Ok I seem to have fixed it. Apparently " @Html.AntiForgeryToken()" was stopping it from giving the error message. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Make sure you add this to the top of your controller: [OutputCache(Location = OutputCacheLocation.None, NoStore = true)]

Comment: Thanks, someone had to tell me about upvoting & accepting too. :)